# Issue with \drawwidebeam on pst-optexp

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-optexp

I'm trying to use pst-optexp with XeLaTeX, but every time I call \drawwidebeam, I get a broken figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,3.3)
    \pnode(0.5,1){A}
    \pnode(3,1){B}
    \optbox[position=start,optboxsize=0.5 1](A)(B)
    \lens[n=2](A)(B)
    %\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!40]{1-2}(B)
    \optbox[position=start,optboxsize=0.5 1,labelangle=90,labeloffset=1.5](0.5,2.5)(3,2.5){No crash yet}
\end{pspicture}

\section{Test 2}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,3.3)
    \pnode(0.5,1){A}
    \pnode(3,1){B}
    \optbox[position=start,optboxsize=0.5 1](A)(B)
    \lens[n=2](A)(B)
    \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!40]{1-2}(B)
    \optbox[position=start,optboxsize=0.5 1,labelangle=90,labeloffset=1.5](0.5,2.5)(3,2.5){Crash!}
\end{pspicture}

\section{Test 3}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,3.3)
    \pnode(0.5,1){A}
    \pnode(3,1){B}
    \optbox[position=start,optboxsize=0.5 1](A)(B)
    \lens[n=2](A)(B)
    \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!40]{1-2}(B)
    \optbox[position=start,optboxsize=0.5 1,labelangle=90,labeloffset=1.5](0.5,2.5)(3,2.5){Crash!}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

I used Sharelatex for this test. I'm also having the same issue with the complete document, with MiKTeX 2.9.6500 and XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998.

1. How can I fix my figure?
2. If there is no easy way to solve this bug, how can I compile my figure with Latex and then import it in XeLaTex?

Comment: `pst-optexp` doesn't work properly with XeLaTeX. Unfortunately, I don't know how I could fix it.